# Can not import pandas in django project?

Tags: django, pandas, python-2.6

I am getting following error then I run application:

```
  File "/var/opt/igp_modules/Mod51_LAM/mod51_LAM.py", line 235, in process
    self.linesStructureCSV(inlist)
  File "/var/opt/igp_modules/Mod51_LAM/mod51_LAM.py", line 610, in linesStructureCSV
    from  line_analysis  import LAM
  File "/var/opt/igp_modules/Mod51_LAM/line_analysis.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2909, in <module>
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/converter.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.units as units
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 709, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 627, in rc_params
    fname = matplotlib_fname()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 565, in matplotlib_fname
    fname = os.path.join(get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 240, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 439, in _get_configdir
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to create %s/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data"%h)
RuntimeError: Failed to create /root/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data
```

but from terminal `pandas` is imported successfully.

```
[iv2user@develpoment-24 igp_modules]$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import pandas
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

**How can I fix this issue**?

**Server details**:

```
OS: CentOS 6.8
Pandas:  0.17.1
Numpy:  1.11.1rc1
```

Comment: Why the matlab tag?

Answer (score 2):

Read the last line of the error message:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create /root/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data
```

matplotlib needs a writable location, and its trying to write to `/root/.matplotlib` and your django server probably doesn't have permission to write there because its not running as root (which is a good thing. Don't run as root just to defeat this).

You've not said how you've launched django (via apache? some other server?) but the fix would seem to be to set that environment variable to a location owned by the user that your django process runs as - possible user `www` or `apache` or something else.

Comment: how you've launched django? Ans: apache